# Calling a function within an each function, within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sure there's something tiny wrong with my syntax... Here is stripped down version of my code...

```
function example1() {
    var thumbWidth = $(this).find('img').width();
    //some more code
};

function example2() {
  $('div').each(function(){
    example1();
    thumbTotal = thumbWidth + xx //etc.;
  });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  example2();
});
```

My problem is that example1 is not being executed in the code above. I've tried inserting the example1 code manually and this works fine. I want to be able to call example1 elsewhere so it's important that it's isolated within a separate function.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the error console in FF, Safari or Chrome? Any errors? What exactly do you want to do? Maybe showing more code from example1() would be more helpful for us.

Comment: I looked in the error console as you suggested which was helpful. It is saying that 'thumbWidth' is undefined. Can it not get a variable from another function?

Comment: Accourding your example you can't get the value, because 'thumbWidth' is out of scope from example2(). It "lives" only in 'example1()'.

Comment: Ah ok, so calculations only live in the scope, just looking into this - do I need to set a 'global variable'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you edited post you've got at least two ways to solve the situation:

1st: Define a return value for example1()

```
function example1() {
    var thumbWidth = $(this).find('img').width();
    //some more code
 };
 function example2() {
  $('div').each(function() {
      thumbTotal = example1() + xx //etc.;
  });
 };
 $(document).ready(function(){
   example2();
 });
```

2nd: Define an appropiate scope for the variable 'thumbWidth'

```
    var thumbWidth;
    function example1() {
        thumbWidth = $(this).find('img').width();
        //some more code
     };
     function example2() {
      $('div').each(function() {
         //or here var thumbWidth;
         example1();     
         thumbTotal = thumbWidth + xx //etc.;
      });
     };

 $(document).ready(function(){
   example2();
 });
```

Answer (score 8):

It might be a copy&paste error, but:
Line 9 should be `});` instead of `)};`

This might cause faulty behavior as javascript code containing syntax errors is often still somehow interpreted causing very strange results.

Comment: True, [here is](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/Z9nNH/) simple test case with the fixed version.

Comment: if this solved the issue could you please accept his answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing obviously wrong with the code (except some syntax error). The principle works just fine.

Some possible reasons why it would fail:

- There is some syntax error, so none of the code is executed.
- The jQuery selector doesn't match any elements.
- You have redefined the name (for example a local variable with the same name) so that the function is not reachable.

The first can be tested by just putting an `alert(1);` somewhere, and see if it shows up. The second can be tested by using `alert($('div').length);` to check how many elements are matched. The third can be tested using `alert(example1);` to see if it shows the code of the function, or something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

```
function example1(yo) {
  return $(yo).find('img').width();
};

function example2() {
    var total=0;
  $('div').each(function(){
    total+=example1(this);
    //Some more code here
  });
  alert(total);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  example2();
});
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

The example2 is bad written, change:

```
  $('div').each(function(){
    example1();
    //Some more code here
  )};
```

by

```
  $('div').each(function(){
    example1();
    //Some more code here
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function example1() {
  //Code
};

function example2() {
  $('div').each(function(){
    example1();
    //Some more code here
  **});**
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  example2();
});
```

in the example2 function there's a misplaced )}

Answer (score 0):

Figured that my problem was to do with calling variables outside the scope of the function. In my case this is not possible because I need the variables to be local since it is looping through divs (therefore the variable will change with each iteration).

Here is an explanation of local vs. global variables. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-jquery